# Changing AngularDart application root url

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-dart

I am trying to get AngularDart to work with nginx. The compiled files from AngularDart are located at `/home/user/project/build`.

If my nginx configuration looks as follows, everything works fine when I open up my browser at `www.example.com`:

```
location / {
  alias /home/user/project/build/;
}
```

However, if I change it to

```
location /static {
  alias /home/user/project/build/;
}
```

and enter `www.example.com/static` in my browser, the browser console says that it could not find lots of scripts, for example `http://www.example.com/packages/angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.ddc.js`. The correct URL of this one would be `http://www.example.com/static/packages/angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.ddc.js`.

Any ideas how I can get the dart compiler to add `/static` to the URLs so that it works?

Comment: make sure youre setting the base, as per https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router/1#set-the-base-href

Comment: that's it, would you like to write this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set the base href.

To do so, add the following tag into your `index.html` file

```
<base href="/static">
```

You can find more info on this [in the documentation](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router/1#set-the-base-href)

Comment: If you are wondering why it did not help, make sure you add it after the line `<script defer src="main.dart.js"></script>`. Do not do that stupid mistake like me :)